# Prove that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a compact set $K$ such that $\mathbb P(K)>1-\varepsilon$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Prove that there exists a compact set $K$ such that $\mathbb P(K)>1-\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon>0$.

My way of proving:

Let F_p(t) be a distribution function of P where P is probability on R. Then  $\lim_{t\to\infty} F_p(t)=1$. Let K=[-a,a] be a compact set K belongs to R. Then F_p(K)=P([-$a$,$a$]). Then let {$a$\to\infty} then lim P([$-a$,$a$])=1. As a result, P(K)=1>1-e.

Does it look mathematical to you guys?

Comment: You should give more details. What space is this? What kind of measure is $P$? (I assume it's a measure.) What is $F_p$?

Comment: F_p is distribution function

Comment: P is probability

Comment: where F_p : R->[0,1]

Comment: $F_p$ is the distribution of what?

Comment: @Justin: please add this to the question. Still, what's the space? $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes, it is R space

Comment: F_p is distribution function of P

Comment: Justin: OK, but add those details to the question. There's a link "edit" below the question. The better the question is formulated, the more likely it is to be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that every compact $K \subset (-\infty, \infty)$ satisfies $P(K) \le 1 - \epsilon$. Observe that:

$$ \mathbb P(\mathbb R) = \mathbb P\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [-n,n] \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb P([-n,n]) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} (1- \epsilon) = 1 - \epsilon$$

This is a contradiction because $\mathbb P(\mathbb R) = 1$.

If you don't like arguments by contradiction, then we might just do:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb P([-n,n]) = \mathbb P\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} [-n,n] \right) = \mathbb P(\mathbb R) = 1$$

Then, for any $\epsilon >0$, there must be $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $1 -  \mathbb P([-n_0, n_0]) < \epsilon$. Put $K = [-n_0, n_0]$ .